# nginx rewrite rules for Joomla!

Tags: nginx, rewrite, joomla

I've got nginx installed on Ubuntu from the repository (v0.7.65), and while with my default site configuration works wonders with WordPress pretty URLs and nginx-compatibility plugin (so far), it doesn't with Joomla!. Here's the configuration:

```
server {
listen   80 default;
server_name  localhost;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

root   /var/www/nginx-default;

location /wordpress {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @wordpress;
}

location /joomla {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @joomla;
}

# Configuración para instalaciones de WordPress
location @wordpress {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9120;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/wordpress/index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

# Configuración para instalaciones de Joomla!
location @joomla {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9120;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/joomla/index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9120;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

I got it to show me the index, the administrator, and one level below links. That is, if I access /joomla/joomla-overview, it works just nice (with friendly URLs and Apache mod_rewrite enabled in Joomla!), but if I try /joomla/joomla-overview/what-is-new-in-1-5, I get [an error](http://tinypic.com/r/2im2qld/6).

What do you think is happening here? Do you know other settings to make it work, preferably within the environment I have it now?

Thanks in advance for your support.

PS: Please, I have not found much help relating my issue. I've tried different solutions, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this has been solved but this nginx config works for my joomla installation.

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  rewrite ^ http://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;
 }
server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  root /home/public_html/example.com/public;
  error_page   404          /404.html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;

  index index.php index.htm index.html;
  # serve static files directly
  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
  }
  location 404.html{
    index /404.html;
  }
  location ~* \.php$ {
    # By all means use a different server for the fcgi processes if you need to
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
  }
  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, it has not been solved yet. I'm not at my machine right now, but I will let you know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: It worked wonders, thank you very much! I can finally go back to nginx.